# AngularJs create module with functions inside service

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a new module to use in my projects, it's a shoppingCart. I know there are some openSource shoppingCart out there, but i need to create my own because of some use restrictions, and company policy, etc..

I could create it and it works everything ok. The only thing I noticed is to make it a real module, where i can use in other projects as well. I know it's possible to achieve it, but since I'm a new user in AngularJs, I don't know how to procced from now.

What i have is a structure like this:

```
angular.module('agCart',[])
.run(['$rootScope','$stateParams','factCart', function ($rootScope,$stateParams,factCart) {
    // ... some other run - not so important..\\
}])

.factory('factCart', ['localStorageService', function (localStorageService) {
    var _getCache = function() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorageService.get("cart"));
    };

    return {
        getCache: _getCache
    };

    //... some other factories ...\\
}])

.controller('CartCtrl',
['$rootScope','$scope','$stateParams',...[more]...,
function($rootScope,$scope,$stateParams,...[more]...) {
    $scope.addItem = function(event) {
        //code to add item
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function(event) {
        //code to remove item
    };

    //... more code ...\\
}]);
```

As you can see, I'm using all the functions to make the cart work from inside a controller, which I know is not the correct way. But that is when my doubt appear.

#### How can i create directives or services to work as these $scope functions?

I've tried to create directives for the shoppingCart with those functions, but i could't apply it to a 'click' event, or comunicate with each other because the shopping cart take effect on 2 arrays:

1. List of products - To create a visual feedback the item is in the chart;
2. The shoppingCart list itself, to populate and save on the user cache;

So, for example, when i click on the 'Add item' button, it will perform 2 main functions.

- Add the item to the cart and save the new array in the storage;
- Modify the product list and apply a `inCart = true` to that specific product;

#### Edit:

The main reason why i want to do this is because right now i need to specify the `CartCtrl` on the view that I want to use it. I'd like to make the cart usable just by adding it's module to the main module of the app.

For example, right now I have 2 projects. One of them is a single e-commerce, only 1 store, so the cart is the same for the whole web and needs to be accessible in all views.

The 2nd project is a combination of e-commerce, it has multiple stores, so each store view needs to have it's own cart. So the cart only need to work on that specific view.

This is why i want to make it more dynamic.

Comment: Really not clear what your specific problems are. Where's the view code that doesn't work calling the click events?

Comment: @charlietfl I edited my question, see if it helps.

Comment: Can you show the directive you tried with? Not really sure what you mean with `I've tried to create directives for the shoppingCart with those functions, but i could't apply it to a 'click' event, or comunicate with each other because the shopping cart take effect on 2 arrays`